# Using values from another table as ENUM values in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's assume that I have `mytable` in mySQL

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `gender` enum('MALE','FEMALE','UNISEX') NOT NULL,
);
```

I don't want to enumerate these values at design time. I want to put them in `another_table` as values.

In `another_table` the `SELECT` values are:

```
ID    NAME
==    ======
01    MALE
02    FEMALE
03    UNISEX
```

I can define the `mytable.gender` as `INT` and combine these two tables in WHERE clause with sth like `mytable.gender=another_table.id`.

Can I create a database level foreign-key relationship with these enum values at design time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you use a [foreign key constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

That will make the database refuse inserts or updates to id values in the `mytable` table that doesn't exist in the `another_table` table, and refuse deletes from the `another_table` table for values that are used in the `mytable` table.

Comment: Thanks, you helped a lot and I could managed to get it working with making both fields as INT(4) types. What if I want to use multiple values from another_table? (MALE and FEMALE values in same row.) I couldn't change the type as SET after my initial setup :(

Comment: @noway: The you would use another table to connect the two tables. You can add a unique constraint to that table, to prevent one record in `mytable` having more than one of each of the values from the `another_table`.